# IOS Safari Input Element cursor location

Tags: ios, input, safari, location, cursor

In iOS Safari, if you type in the input box and delete it again, the cursor position will be incorrect if there is a placeholder in the input box. Do you know the debugging point?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4eoyLr5qFI

Comment: ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'keyup' }"